# What non-parametric statistical test can I use that compares difference taking into account 2 independent variables and 1 dependent variable?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

What non-parametric statistical test can I use that compares the significance difference taking into account 2 independent variables and 1 dependent variable?

For example,
The first independent variable is speed: 1, 2, 3, 4
The second independent variable is group: A, B, C, D

Group A has 7 individuals, Group B has 4 individuals, Group C has 10 individuals, and Group D has 6 individuals

All individuals have 1 score per speed.

I want to know if there is a significant difference between the over all performance of the 4 groups. So the test should be something similar to Kruskal Wallis test but taking into account an extra variable. Thank you

Comment: So basically, you're looking for nonparametric two-way ANOVA? If so, Friedman test might be an option.

Comment: (a) I believe Friedman test requires a balanced design. (b) Your design is obviously unbalanced, but the degree of imbalance is not obvious; in particular one would want to know if there is at least one score for each Group-by-speed cell. Presumably speed is ordinal; are Groups nominal? (c) The dataset seems small enough to post, and I suppose you will have a better chance of a helpful answer if data are available. (d) There are a couple of posts on this site about unbalanced 2-way ANOVAs. Depending on data, it might be possible to do a permutation test with 2-way F-statistic as metric.